# Change SSH repo url in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I have gitlab on my server. URL, for example: https://git.site.com

On project page I have similar URL for my repo:

[image]

How I can change path only for ssh repo path? I need IP address of my server, not URL

Answer (score 1):

Change this in the **/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

> gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'gitssh.example.com'

and then run gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at `external_url` configuration field: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab

If you're using Omnibus, you can also custom the SSH host: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template#L39